# c# Bluetooth LE - write configuration error - ValueChanged never called

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I try to connect my c# WPF program to a BLE device and this is the code to connect to the device:

```
private async Task ConnectToWatcher(DeviceInformation deviceInfo) {
        try {
            // get the device
            BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

            // get the GATT service
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            var gattServicesResult = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_SERVICE_UUID));
            service = gattServicesResult.Services[0];

            // get the GATT characteristic
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            var gattCharacteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_CHAR_UUID));
            characteristic = gattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics[0];

            // register for notifications
            Thread.Sleep(150);

            characteristic.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => {
                Debug.WriteLine($"[{device.Name}] Received notification containing {args.CharacteristicValue.Length} bytes");
            };

            GattWriteResult result =
            await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorWithResultAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Characteristics write result: status={result.Status}, protocolError={result.ProtocolError}");

        } catch (Exception ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x800710df) {
            Debug.WriteLine("bluetooth error 1");
            // ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE because the Bluetooth radio is not on.
        }
    }
```

The line

```
 Debug.WriteLine($"Characteristics write result: status={result.Status}, protocolError={result.ProtocolError}"
```

creates the output
**Characteristics write result: status=protocolError, protocolError=3**
I couldn't find anywhere whats that supposed to mean. The effect is the Method **characteristic.ValueChanged** never gets called.

Do I have to do more to have the characteristic configurated? And has anybody any idea why the method isn't called or what that error message means?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, some Windows 10 builds have a COM security bug.
Solution was to register for Windows-Insider-Program and update Windows.

**Update:**
There are two more solutions to this:
1) Calling CoInitializeSecurity from outside your c#-code (didn't bring it to work)
- or- 
2) Writing two new keys into the windows registry. You cann create a file "Bluetooth.reg", which will add those two keys on a doubleklick. This answer from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk was my solution:

> Hi Kamen, I have experienced exactly same issue. You can give a quick try of the following:
>
> ---
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID{C6BFD646-3DF0-4DE5-B7AF-5FFFACB844A5}]
>   "AccessPermission"=hex:01,00,04,80,9c,00,00,00,ac,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,\
>     00,00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,07,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
>     05,0a,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,03,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,\
>     00,00,18,00,07,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
>     00,18,00,03,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,0f,02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
>     14,00,03,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,13,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,03,00,00,\
>     00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,14,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,\
>     20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\YOURAPP.exe]
>   "AppID"="{C6BFD646-3DF0-4DE5-B7AF-5FFFACB844A5}"

---

> 1. Copy above content to a text file.
> 2. Replace 'YOURAPP.EXE' with your executable name
> 3. Optionally replace GUIDs (I have created a new one for you)
> 4. Save text file with an extension as .reg
> 5. Double click on the file.
> 6. You would see a message 'The Keys and values contained in ..... .reg have been successfully added to the registry.'
>
> With this, I don't need to call CoInitializeSecurity from my app.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the **Characteristics write result: status=protocolError, protocolError=3** error when calling the function below in C#.

```
await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorWithResultAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify)
```

The issue was the BLE Characteristic that I was trying to get Notify data from did not have a BLE Descriptor.

ESP32 C++ from the BLE Bluetooth server/device:

```
BLEService *service = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
BLECharacteristic* characteristic = service->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);

// This code was missing and causing the error
BLEDescriptor *descriptor = new BLEDescriptor((uint16_t)0x2902);
descriptor->setValue("The Descriptor Is No Longer Missing");
characteristic->addDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to call CoInitializeSecurity before

more info here. couple of weeks I spent looking for solution :)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17707088)

Comment: Hello Eriawan, I think essential info is to **call CoInitializeSecurity**. that alone provide solution to the problem. By marking this answer negative you are might cause other people spend their time on wrong solutions.