# c# Bluetooth LE - ValueChanged never called - additional configuration necessary?

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My question is kinda an update to my last question: 
[c# Bluetooth LE - write configuration error - ValueChanged never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163685/c-sharp-bluetooth-le-write-configuration-error-valuechanged-never-called)

The problem is, I connect my WPF c#-Application to my BLE device, but characteristic.ValueChanged is never called. Maybe I miss something with the configuration or need to send additionall configuration to the device, idk.

Here is the method connecting the application to the device:

```
private async Task ConnectToWatcher(DeviceInformation deviceInfo) {
    try {
        // get the device
        BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

        // get the GATT service
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        var gattServicesResult = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_SERVICE_UUID));
        service = gattServicesResult.Services[0];

        // get the GATT characteristic
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        var gattCharacteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_CHAR_UUID));
        characteristic = gattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics[0];

        // register for notifications
        Thread.Sleep(150);

        characteristic.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{device.Name}] Received notification containing {args.CharacteristicValue.Length} bytes");
        };

        enableTXNotification();

    } catch (Exception ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x800710df) {
        Debug.WriteLine("bluetooth error 1");
        // ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE because the Bluetooth radio is not on.
    }
}
```

And here's the method sending the configuration:

```
public async void enableTXNotification()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("enableTXNotification");

        var gattCharacteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid(TX_CHAR_UUID));
        if (gattCharacteristicsResult == null
                || gattCharacteristicsResult.Status != GattCommunicationStatus.Success
                || gattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics == null
                || gattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics?.Count < 1)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(" Failed to find GATT characteristic.");
            return;
        }
        txCharacteristic = gattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics[0];

        txCharacteristic.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => {
            Debug.WriteLine("[{device.Name}] Received notification containing {args.CharacteristicValue.Length} bytes");
        };

        Debug.WriteLine(" Writing CCCD...");
        GattWriteResult result =
            await txCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorWithResultAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
        Debug.WriteLine($" Characteristics write result: status={result.Status}, protocolError={result.ProtocolError}");
}
```

The last line creates the output **status=success**. Still no ValueChanged Method (I suspect the second one to be unnecassary) is being called when I use the device.
I'm running out of ideas. Can someone help?

Comment: You seem to have already asked this question one day before...  If you want to expand on that question then just edit it, don't keep re-posting the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

you should first verify that the CharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor is "Notify", if not you should set it to notify and then define the ValueChanged listener.
try to change "ConnectToWatcher" with the following code:

```
private async Task ConnectToWatcher(DeviceInformation deviceInfo) {
try {
    // get the device
    BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

    // get the GATT service
    Thread.Sleep(150);
    var gattServicesResult = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_SERVICE_UUID));
    service = gattServicesResult.Services[0];

    // get the GATT characteristic
    Thread.Sleep(150);
    var gattCharacteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_CHAR_UUID));
    characteristic = gattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics[0];

    // check Characteristic Configuration Descriptor
    var currentDescriptorValue = await characteristic.ReadClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync();

    if (currentDescriptorValue.ClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor != GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify)
    {
         var status = await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
    }

    // register for notifications
    Thread.Sleep(150);

    characteristic.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => {
        Debug.WriteLine($"[{device.Name}] Received notification containing {args.CharacteristicValue.Length} bytes");
    };

    enableTXNotification();

} catch (Exception ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x800710df) {
    Debug.WriteLine("bluetooth error 1");
    // ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE because the Bluetooth radio is not on.
}
```

}

hope it helped

Comment: If I try this I get an exception: The attribute cannot be written. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650003).

I think it's because the characteristic is not a write characteristic, but the characteristic, that sends the information from the device to the application.

Comment: If i try the same with **WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorWithResultAsync** I get a **protocolError 3** whatever that means.

Comment: it is seems like the Characteristic is not defined as Notify Characteristic (not contains Notify flag) so it does not firing the value changed event and therefore  you not getting any action on the event listener. also it is read only so you cannot change it's flag from your project

Comment: When I connect to that characteristic with an Android App, everything works fine.